# Sitecore EXM List Manager in distributed environment with Lucene Search Configuration

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, ecm, sitecore-exm

We are using **Lucene** index instead of Solr. We are currently facing an issue with our List Manager in CD server. The below code throws an exception in CD server as it's unable to instantiate List Manger from Sitecore Configuration Factory.

```
newsRecipientList = listRepository.GetEditableRecipientCollection("{my list guid }");
```

I've already gone through the Sitecore documentation for List Manager in a scaled environment, but it only talks about Solr.
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/the_list_manager/configure_the_list_manager_in_a_scaled_environment

Any guidance on Sitecore configuration for List Manager using Lucene is much appreciated.

***Sitecore Exception Stacktrace***

> **Value can not be null : listManager**
>   at
>   Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Factories.BusinessLogicFactory.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__b()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.InstanceCreator.GetConfiguredInstanceOrDefault[TResult](String
>   configurationPath, Func`1 defaultInstanceBuilder)    at
>   Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Factories.BusinessLogicFactory.<>c__DisplayClassd.<CreateDefaultFactory>b__a()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Factories.InitializedOnce`1.get_Value()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.ListManager.ListManagerCollectionRepository.GetEditableRecipientCollection(String
>   recipientCollectionId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since List Manager is not available in CD environment we need to call Sitecore API to update/add contacts. Below class has api's to modify contact list.

```
Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.ClientApi
```

We need to add connection string in CD server in order to call this api's.

```
<add name="EmailCampaignClientService" connectionString="url=http://<Your CM Server host>/sitecore%20modules/web/emailcampaign/ecmclientservice.asmx;timeout=60000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

if you followed the guide to the Delivery environment, ListManager is disabled and that might be the reason why you see that error. Does the same code work on CM? (where LM is enabled)

Comment: ListManager is not supposed to be available on CD servers, which is why the documentation states that you must disable it on such servers.

Comment: We are getting visitors information such as Name and email and then trying to add that recipient in the list. How we can add recipient in list if list manager is not available on cd server.

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to expose a service on the CM to perform the operation.